# Computer turns on and off repeatedly

Tags: infinite-loop

My Dell laptop won't turn on! When I press the power button it starts up for half a second and then turns off. This will repeat until I take out the battery or unplug the charger. Speaking of the charger, when I plug it in the charging light comes on for a second or two and then turns off. The light does not come back on. I have no way of telling if the computer is actually charging or not. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would ask this as a comment but I don't have enough rep. When the charger is taken out. Are you able to turn it on at all? It almost sounds like your power brick is dying and it can't give enough power to the computer to boot correctly, especially if the charger light will only come on for a second before turning back off. That is usually a direct link to the mother board so unless there's an issue with your mother board (which you can say good bye laptop), it sounds like a bad charger.

Comment: You could probably rewrite this as a potential answer: you are describing the female power inlet on the motherboard detaching from the motherboard from mechanical stress. Very common. One simple way to test this is to apply very gentle pressure to the charger plug and see if you can keep the light on. If you can and then it goes out when you let go, then there is a high chance that the motherboard connection is loose or broken. Usually when one says "the charger is broken" this means the power brick, not the motherboard jack.

Comment: Sounds like you know quite a bit more about this, you might want to add your answer. I worded it like I did because I have had a similar problem with my power brick on my laptop.